# C# project reference F# class lib in netcoreapp3.1

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I've just created a simple class lib in F# that has the following `fsproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Dto.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now I want to reference this in a C# project that has the following `csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Splunk" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\<path>\<to>\<file>.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

In the controller I now try to references the types in the F# class lib, but I do get the following compiler error:

> Controllers/ProviderController.cs(4,53): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Types' does not exist in the namespace 'App.Api' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/src/some more path Api/File.csproj]
> Controllers/ProviderController.cs(22,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Provider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/homepath.csproj]

The actual controller looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NamespaceTo.Types.Dto;

namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    public class ProviderController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ProviderController> _logger;

        public ProviderController(ILogger<ProviderController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Provider> Get()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like the F# project isn't recognized at all since I don't get any intellisense on the types defined in F#. The build also fails as mentioned. Anything I'm missing to use F# types in a C# netcoreapp3.1 project?

The `Dto.fs` file in the F# project:

```
module Api.Types.Dto
open System

type Provider = {
    Id: string
    Name: string
    Logo: string
}

type Text = {
    Short: string
    Long: string
}

type ProductTexts = {
    Default: Text
    Alternatives: Text
}

type ProductAlternative = {
    Id: string
    IsDefault: bool
    Priority: int
    ContractLength: int
    MonthlyPrice: float
    EffectiveRate: float
    StartupFee: float
    MonthlyFee: float
    TotalPrice: float
    TotalCost: float
}

type Product = {
    Id: string
    Name: string
    Priority: int
    Provider: Provider
    Texts: ProductTexts
    MinimumAmount: float
    MaximumAmount: float
    Alternatives: ProductAlternative list
}

type ProductResponse = {
    Updated: DateTime
    ArticleId: string
    Price: float
    Currency: string
    OperatingChain: string
}

type PaymentOption = {
    ArticleIds: string list
    Product: Product
}

type PaymentOptionsResponse = PaymentOption list
```

### Update:

I do have the same issue when I try to use the project from another F# console app.

Comment: C# --> F# requires you to build the F# project to "see" it in C#, at least within Visual Studio. Is that your environment?

Comment: Please show how `Dto.fs` looks like.

Comment: @Hostel, added the dto.fs file.

Comment: @PhillipCarter, I haven't had any problems with this before I think. I'm using code. Shouldn't dotnet build also build the project that is referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted on Slack:
An initial concern is going to be that `Api.Types.Dto`is a top-level `module` and not `namespace` - this is implicitly using the namespace `Api.Types` and adding the `Dto` module to it.
C# sees `Dto` therefore as a type, not a namespace that can be opened - and the inner types such as `Provider` are just that, to C#, nested types.

There are two resolution paths here:
The first is to open the namespace: `using Api.Types` and then dot into the nested types: `Dto.Provider`
The second is to `using static Api.Types.Dto`

Comment: was probably something like that, definitely a user mistake no matter how you twist and turns it :D